# Which passport authentication to use

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm using several Passport authentication strategies in my site, which works great, however, I need a `Demo` or (we could call `session` ) Strategy which automatically authorize the user by it's session id, Now I'm doing it manually, when the user navigates to the `/demo` page, I run a query on the db (mongodb), with the session id, and if the user exists, I render the page with that user, if not I create one.

```
app.get('/demo', function(req,res) {
  db.User.findOne({ 'accounts.kind': 'demo', 'accounts.sid': req.sessionID }, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
      res.render( 'home', {
        user: user
      });
    } else {
      var user = new db.User();
      user.accounts.push({
        kind: 'demo',
        sid: req.sessionID,
        created: Date.now
      });
      req.session.userId = user._id;

      user.save(function(err) {
        if(err) { throw err; }
        res.render( 'home', {
          user: user
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

the user schema looks like this:

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
  uname: {type: String},
  accounts: [],
  docs:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Doc'}]
})
```

It works, but I need to set a session variable, because this method does not log in the user, I mean there is no `req.user` in the requests, but with that session variable I can check whether the user is a demo user.

```
if (req.user) {
    userid = req.user._id.toString();
  } else {
    userid = req.session.userId;
  }
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this, with one of the existing passport Strategies. I see that there's [passport-http](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http), and [passport-anonymous](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-anonymous), and several others, but I'm not sure which should I use.

It's important to me to create a database entry for the user. So later I can attach to it an another account.

Comment: Doesn't that work with cookies?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, it involves cookies, the session id is in a cookie,

Comment: Then you don't need a strategy. serialization and deserialization should work automatically and retrieve the session when the user comes back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve it like this:
Defined a new Strategy,

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , util = require('util');

function DemoStrategy(options, verify) {
  if (typeof options == 'function') {
    verify = options;
    options = {};
  }
  if (!verify) throw new Error('Demo Basic authentication strategy requires a verify function');

  passport.Strategy.call(this);
  this.name = 'demo';
  this._verify = verify;
}

util.inherits(DemoStrategy, passport.Strategy);

DemoStrategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req) {
  var self = this;
  this._verify( req, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return self.error(err); }
    self.success(user);
  });
}

module.exports.Strategy = DemoStrategy;
```

the route:

```
app.get('/auth/demo', 
    passport.authenticate('demo'),
    function(req,res) { 
      res.redirect('/');
     }
  );
```

and the passport.use part:

```
passport.use(new DemoStrategy( 
  function(req, done) {
    console.log( 'using demo strategy, req: ', req );
    if (req.user) {
      // place code here, if we want to attach to an existing account
    } else {
      db.User.findOne({ 'accounts.kind': 'demo', 'accounts.sid': req.sessionID }, function(err, dbuser) {
        if (dbuser) {
          done(null,dbuser);
        } else {
          var user = new db.User();
          user.accounts.push({
            kind: 'demo',
            sid: req.sessionID,
            created: Date.now
          });

          user.save(function(err) {
            if(err) { throw err; }
            done(null,user);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
));
```

Maybe it's full of bugs, and the error handling is not complete, but seems like the right solution, it's integrated into the much appreciated [passport](http://passportjs.org/) library,

Comment: is this really the best way to use session information to authenticate a user so they don't have to re-input their username/password?

Comment: it was a temporary user (try demo user) in my case, which could be turned into a  fully registered user. I used many passport auth strategies, so it fitted well into my app.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, creating a custom strategy is unnecessary in this case. I found out that the official [LocalStrategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) has an (undocumented) `passReqToCallback` option, which enables you to access `req` object in the verify function. You can use it to do all kinds of stuff using the LocalStrategy only by altering the verify function:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, username, password, done) {
    //now that you have req object, you can
    //probably do whatever you need to do right here
});
```

Please mind that the function now takes 4 arguments `req, username, password, done`, beginning with `req` object, instead of the default 3.

I hope this saves you some time, I spent like an hour trying to work around this before going through the LocalStrategy code.

Comment: Just a note: The other strategies also has this option.I'm already using LocalStrategy, i don't think it can be used twice.

Comment: You can actually use it multiple times, you just have to give it a name on the passport config like:
`passport.use('other-login', new LocalStrategy());`

And then in the routes:
`app.post('/otherlogin', passport.authenticate('other-login'));`. Giving no name, the LocalStrategy has a default name of 'local'

Answer (score 2):

Check out Section 4 from the [passport configuration](http://passportjs.org/guide/configuration.html). This is the code to put the session-id into a cookie and retrieve the data when the user comes back. No strategy required.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have these functions, but these are called by the passport.session() middleware (if I'm right), when I use my demo auth, passport is skipped completly.

Comment: by design :) Finally I created a new strategy, see below (or above)

Comment: Hmm, ok. Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: no no, the description of my problem was weak. thanks for your time, still I learned something from your answer.